# Embedding Javascript in HTML in Javascript (Oi!)

Tags: javascript, html, timeline

Alright... I'm trying to write some javascript code that will apply to an html block, which itself appears in a javascript file. It's a complete mess. Here's a sample:

```
[new Date(1942,01,01), , '<div onclick="this.nextSibling.style.display=\'block\'; this.style.display=\'none\'"><img src="img/content/michenerCenterThumb.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" /></div><div style="display:none"><iframe width="200" height="165" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/in7IUzjN3pY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'],
```

[edit] I'm using Timeline, which is available here: http://links.sourceforge.net/#timeline. Part of building a timeline involves adding entries, like in this sample:

```
data.addRows([
      [new Date(2010,7,23), , 'Conversation<br>' + 
        '<img src="img/comments-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'],
      [new Date(2010,7,23,23,0,0), , 'Mail from boss<br>' + 
        '<img src="img/mail-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'],
      [new Date(2010,7,24,16,0,0), , 'Report'],
      [new Date(2010,7,26), new Date(2010,8,2), 'Traject A'],     
      [new Date(2010,7,28), , 'Memo<br>' + 
        '<img src="img/notes-edit-icon.png" style="width:48px; height:48px;">'],
      [new Date(2010,7,29), , 'Phone call<br>' + 
        '<img src="img/Hardware-Mobile-Phone-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'],
      [new Date(2010,7,31), new Date(2010,8,3), 'Traject B'],     
      [new Date(2010,8,4,12,0,0), , 'Report<br>' +
        '<img src="img/attachment-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">']
    ]);
```

In the html, I want to implement jquery ui, highslider, etc., but this becomes messy very fast (like in my above example.) What is "doing it right" in this instance?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: If you start from the assumption that you "need" to use JavaScript to create html that contains inline event attributes containing JavaScript then the above is pretty much what you'll get. What do you actually do with that string of html? If you're asking whether there is some other way that JavaScript can create html elements and assign event handlers to those elements the answer is "yes". What is the context of the above? Is it sitting within an array of other very similar html items?

Comment: You will one day get caught in a recursive loop that will destroy this universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a more elegant solution... closer, I hope, to what constitutes proper coding. The html of each element is now written on the html page. I read this by using a custom getElementsByClassName which inserts each item class into an array. This array then populates the timeline.

The html:

```
<div class="item" date="1956,1,1" enddate="1967,1,1">
Some Content    
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var items = getElementsByClassName("item"); 
    for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
         var date = items[x].getAttribute("date"); 
         var enddate = items[x].getAttribute("enddate"); 
         var html = items[x].innerHTML; 
            if (!enddate) {
                items[x]=[new Date(date), enddate, html];
            } else {         
                items[x]=[new Date(date), new Date(enddate), html]; 
            }
        }

    data.addColumn('datetime', 'start');
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'end');
    data.addColumn('string', 'content');

    data.addRows(items);
```

You can find the custom getElementsByClassName here: http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/